# How to get the $load respond and print it out

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
var $respond=$("#sql").load("sql/loaduser.php);
```

I want to alert the $respond it only gives me object object, how can I see the info, I echo something in php in it, so I want to see that.

Answer (score 2):

`load` returns a jQuery object, alerting an object results in [Object object], you can use `$.get` utility function.

```
$.get('sql/loaduser.php', function(data){
    $("#sql").html(data);
    alert(data);
}, 'html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use jQuery's [AJAX-get()-Method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).
You can do whatever you want in the callback function, which is called with the returned data as its first argument.